# Is there a reverse "De-crapify" type software

Tags: testing, environment

I'm looking into setting up a test environment for my software that would mimic a user's setup. This means a computer setup with a ton of adware, pop-ups, McAffee, and the like. Is there an automated way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Might be a better question for SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

[This series](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/08/download-me-ii-removing-the-remnants-of-the-webs-most-dangerous-search-terms/) from ArsTechnica had an author getting and then removing a bunch of junk from the internet. If you follow his first steps to set up the "bad" environment that might work.